# What does this code mean in plain english?

Tags: smarty

```
{if $GLOBALS.current_user.group.id != "Employer"}
        <li><a href="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/find_jobs/" >[[Find Jobs]]</a></li>
        <li class="sep"></li>
        <li><a href="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/add_listing/?listing_type_id=Resume" >[[Post     Resumes]]</a></li>
        <li class="sep"></li>
    {/if}
```

Just trying to figure out this code. I think it is saying "If the current user IS? or ISN'T? a member or the group 'employer' put the following links in..."

Which is it?

Thanks

Comment: BTW : this is not PHP, it looks like Smarty....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`!=` means `is not equal to`, the exclamation point (`!`) is a [negation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php):

```
$a = 5;

if ($a == 5) {
   // executed if condition is true
}

if ($a != 5) {
   // executed if condition is not true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`!=` means "not equals", so "If the current user ISN'T an employer..."

Answer (score 1):

"isn't" (because of the `!=`)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is in some sort of templating language?  That isn't what normal PHP looks like.  In any case, the `!=` definitely means IS NOT, so it means if the current user IS NOT an employer, insert the links.

Answer (score 0):

**`!=`**
not equal
thus if they are not group.id employer then put in the list items and anchor tags

Answer (score 0):

If the `id` is not equal to "Employer", then condition is satisfied, process inner block which appears to be adding `<li>`'s to the page

Answer (score 0):

Weird code. But it means `Show this html elements if group of current user IS NOT Employer`.

Comment: it looks like a code from Smarty, that's probably why it looks so wierd to people who only work with php ;-)

Comment: I don't work with php at all. Concerning that part: `$GLOBALS.current_user.group.id != "Employer"` - This looks like gibberish to me. Why is the current_user stored in a global? Why is an id a title? Not to mention that links and urls are all written by hand. Guess I'm too far away from PHP. Nevermind. :)

Comment: @gmcalab - golfer? This didn't help me either: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=golfer ;-)

Comment: Obviously you're not a golfer.